# host custom checkbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with checkbox and I downloaded Material Skin from the NuGet package that provides material checkbox I want to use this material check inside my datagridview.

Link Of Material Skin NuGet Package:-https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin/

I tried but it's giving an exception :

> **System.FormatException:** Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type. To replace this default dialog please handle the data error event

```
 class ChackBoxColuman : DataGridViewColumn
    {

        public ChackBoxColuman() : base(new ChackBoxCell())
        {
        }



        public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CellTemplate;
            }
            set
            {
                // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
                if (value != null &&
                    !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChackBoxCell)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a ChackBoxCedll");
                }
                base.CellTemplate = value;
            }
        }

    }

    class ChackBoxCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell {

        public ChackBoxCell() : base() {
            this.Style.Format = "";
        }



        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,dataGridViewCellStyle);
            ChackBoxEdit ctr = DataGridView.EditingControl as ChackBoxEdit;
            if (this.Value == null)
            {
                ctr.Checked = false;
            }
            else {

                ctr.Checked = System.Convert.ToBoolean(this.Value);
            }
        }

        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
                return typeof(ChackBoxEdit);
            }
        }


        public override Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(bool);
            }

        }


    }



    class ChackBoxEdit : MaterialChackbox,IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;

       public ChackBoxEdit():base() {

        }

        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        public int EditingControlRowIndex {

            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }

        }
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged {

            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;
            }
               }

        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor {

            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }




        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange {

            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Checked;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Checked =Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            }
        }


        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        }

        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }
        //Get
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return this.Checked;
        }

        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        //

        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
        {
            // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
            // have changed.
            valueChanged = true;
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            base.OnCheckedChanged(eventargs);
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
        // property.



    }
```

Comment: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells). You can find a whole host of examples about many other customization features there.

Comment: I tried to do but I can't a success

Comment: Post what you tried and didn't work, then.

Comment: see I posted my code which I tried

Comment: Read again what you have found there. You cannot implement just some pieces of it. The first paragraph states: *(...) you can create your own column types with cells that host controls of your choosing. To do this, you must define classes that derive from DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell. You must also define a class that derives from Control and implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface.*. Note the use of **must**, not **should**.

Comment: thanks for your response, I implemented code but it has given an exception please can you give any solution see the new code I posted